# Como resolver esse problema do CakePHP no Mac?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

```
Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake-teste/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake-teste/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line 23

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake-teste/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake-teste/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line 23
```

Estou usando o Mac e não tem `wamp` para Mac.

Comment: Você rodou o comando `composer install`? Se não me engano, o arquivo `autoload.php` é gerado no ato desse comando.

Comment: Gustavo podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar mais informação se quiseres. Juntei à pergunta o que tinhas colocado como resposta.

Comment: Não tem WindowsAMP pra MAC mesmo fera, mas tem MacAMP e roda muito bem do bitnami, uso e recomendo https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp

Comment: Sim rodei o composer Install

Answer (score 1):

Tentou ver se tem algo relacionado a permissão?

Poderia também tentar com o MAMP ao invés do xampp, já tive diversos problemas com esse carinha ai.

https://www.mamp.info/en/

Comment: Mas estou usando e mac não tem wamp.

Comment: WAMP -> Windows Apache MySQL PHP ( Windows != Mac )

Comment: Desculpa, quiz dizer MAMP: https://www.mamp.info/en/
Mas o ideal na verdade seria instalar separadamente tudo que realmente precisa, para facilitar as instalações eu recomendo o uso de homebrew ou macport.

Comment: Recomendo sempre usar o MAMP em vez de outros, o MAMP já esta no mercado a mais tempo, quero dizer, quando se diz a respeito do MAC.